# Android annoying hang on application crash

Tags: android

I guess it's an issue that everybody suffers from but I'm wondering if there's anyway to fix it.

Whenever an application crashes due to an uncaught exception, the screen turns black, the device hangs for several long seconds, afterwards a system message pops up saying the application has crashed and gives an opportunity to report the crash.

Now its really annoying to wait all that time just so I could force-close the app and send a report. Is there any other way to gracefully close the app when an uncaught exception is thrown?

I already have a class that implements `UncaughtExceptionHandler` in which I send an error log. The question is if I can somehow add code to it that will shorten this hang after an app crash.

Thanks!